# passing $scope variable to a function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've been trying to create a generic `function` in angular that changes a `$scope` parameters value.

I've been wondering why I cannot pass `$scope.var` as an `argument` to a `function` e.g.:

```
webApp.controller ('VotesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.param = 42;

    change($scope.param);
    function change(contextParam) {
      contextParam = (Math.random()*100)+1;
    };
});
```

When I ran this function `$scope.param` remains 42.

Is there an alternative besides:

```
webApp.controller ('VotesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.param = 42;

    change('param');
    function change(contextParam) {
      $scope[contextParam] = (Math.random()*100)+1;
    };
});
```

[My Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/9996W3Io4KewA3tgokQR?p=preview)

Comment: What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: To understand why http://plnkr.co/edit/9996W3Io4KewA3tgokQR?p=preview is not working. And if the solution I gave is the only way

Comment: I would avoid passing around scoped Items like this, if you need to pass it into a function I would define it locally and pass that in.  If you wanted to change the scoped value then you could just call the scoped item inside the function without a need to pass it in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is "Don't bind to primitive values".  See http://stsc3000.github.io/blog/2013/10/26/a-tale-of-frankenstein-and-binding-to-service-values-in-angular-dot-js/

```
var webApp = angular.module('webApp', []);

//controllers
webApp.controller ('VotesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.param = { value: 42 };

    change($scope.param);
    function change(contextParam) {
      contextParam.value = (Math.random()*100)+1;
    };
});
```

Comment: Or you pass the entire $scope object to the function instead. Not keen on passing scope or its attributes around, so either option is not great imo.