# passing $scope object to a function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I asked yesterday a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510817/passing-scope-variable-to-a-function-in-angularjs) yet there is a difference.
I'm trying to create a **generic** `function` that will change a `scope` `object`(not primitive)
yet it seems not to be working and I don't understand why?

**My code:**

```
webApp.controller ('VotesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.param = {name: 'Ron', age: 18};        

    change($scope.param);

    function change(contextParam) {
      contextParam = {name:'dan', age: 12};
    }
});
```

It seems `change` `function` does not make any change on `$scope.param` even though I'm
passing a `reference`.

When I'm doing the change like the code below, it is working!

```
webApp.controller ('VotesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.param = {name: 'Ron', age: 18};

    change($scope.param);

    function change(contextParam) {
      contextParam.name = 'dan';
      contextParam.age = 12;
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? how can you explain this behavior?

[My Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/kaEOlRQPNNftoZU7HGI4?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contectParam` is a reference to an object. When you use the assign operator `=`, you change the value of the `contextParam` variable - it stops being a reference to an object and takes a completely different value.

However, when you access the properties of the object referenced by `contextParam`, you change their values, thus making your changes be visible outside the function's scope.

As a side note, it would be much better if you did things this way:

```
function change() {
    return {name: 'dan', age: 12};
}
$scope.param = change();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, another option is to use `$.extend(true, configContext, {name:'dan', age: 12})`